# Change stage titleProperty on selecting different tabs in javafx

Tags: java, events, javafx

I guess there should be some event for this, but didn't find any. The code I have now is

```
stage.titleProperty().bind(tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().textProperty());
```

But it doesn't change the title dynamically, what's the right solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puce's explanation is correct.  Here is a change listener example.

```
stage.setTitle(tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getText());
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {
  @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> tab, Tab oldTab, Tab newTab) {
    stage.setTitle(newTab.getText());
  }
});
```

Use the above code instead of the sample code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a solution right now, but I think I spot the problem:
You've bound the titleProperty to the textProperty of the tab which was selected at binding time. You probably need to listen for selection changes and change the stage title in the listener.

Comment: I didn't find any "selection change listener"

Comment: You could add a listener to tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()